Prove that an open subset of $\mathbb{R^n}$ is equal to union of rational balls with rational radius
My goal is to prove the following result:

Let $A \subset \mathbb R^n$ be an arbitrary open and non-empty set.
Moreover, define
$$ B = A \cap \mathbb Q^n  $$
and for each $b \in B$, let
$$ R_b := \{ r \in \mathbb Q^+ : B(b,r) \subset A \}. $$
Then, there holds
$$ A = \bigcup_{b \in B, \\ r \in R_b} B(b,r). $$

My attempt. I started by analysing the inclusion $(\supset)$. Consider an arbitrary element $ y \in \bigcup_{b \in B, \\ r \in R_b} B(b,r)$. Then, there exists an element $b \in B$ and $r \in R_b$ such that $y \in B(b,r)$. By definition of $R_b$, we directly conclude that $y \in A$.
On the other hand, the inclusion $(\subset)$ seems a bit more complex and I don't know how to deal with it.
Thanks for any help in advance.

Since $A$ is open, for any $a \in A$, there exists some $R > 0$ with $R \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $B(a, R) \subset A$. Thus we can choose some $r \in \mathbb{Q}$ with $0 < r < R$ such that $B(a, r) \subset A$. Then there exists some $q \in \mathbb{Q}^n$ such that $q \in B\left (a, \frac{r}{3}\right )$ (as $\mathbb{Q}^n$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^n$) i.e. $q \in B$.
Thus $a \in B\left (q, \frac{r}{3}\right )$. We also see $B\left (q, \frac{r}{3} \right ) \subset B(a, r)$ since for any $z \in B\left (q, \frac{r}{3} \right )$ we have $|z - a| \leq |z - q| + |q - a| \leq \frac{r}{3} + \frac{r}{3} < r$. Hence, $B\left (q, \frac{r}{3} \right ) \subset A$ so $\frac{r}{3} \in R_q$ and $a \in \displaystyle \bigcup_{\substack{b \in B\\ r \in R_b}} B(b, r)$.
We finally have $A \subset \displaystyle \bigcup_{\substack{b \in B\\ r \in R_b}} B(b, r)$, and so using your result we conclude $A = \displaystyle \bigcup_{\substack{b \in B\\ r \in R_b}} B(b, r)$.

Thanks for your answer. It is very good. I just have one very simple question: is there any particular reason to choose the fraction $r/3$ ? I think that taking $r/2$ also works (and any other number greater than $2$...). Do you agree?

@TemirbekAlikhadzhiyev No particular reason, I just wanted to avoid any issues with thinking if I had to deal with any edge cases, and $\frac{r}{3}$ just avoided it. $\frac{r}{2}$ definitely works with my argument though.
